# How to remove iPad's Popover arrow and its frame border

Tags: ipad, popover

Basically these are two questions:

1. How to remove iPad's popover view's arrow?
2. is there any way to remove popover's black border?

If not possible, can you suggest a way in iPad to display an UIView (popover) at the top of screen without arrow and border (might be light transparent border), please? thanks a lot.

And I don't think ModalView is a proper option, as it cannot be resized and cannot be dismissed by clicking outside modal view.

Comment: Thanks all. Seems that there is no straight way to remove those, has to customize popover. What I'm thinking is to implement a full screen transparent UIView, and add another smaller sized View on the top. so that when it is displayed, it behaves like a popover.

Answer (score 7):

AFIK there is no built-in way to specify "no arrow", or to have a popup sans borders.

This a hack, but it basically works.  In the context of your view controller that is managed by the popup controller, during viewWillAppear:, get the popup window and remove the first layer, which is what renders the arrow and border:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    UIView* v = self.view.superview;
    NSLog( @"%@", NSStringFromClass( [v class]) ); // this should print UIView

    v = v.superview;
    NSLog( @"%@", NSStringFromClass( [v class]) ); // this should print UIPopoverView

    [[v.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

I suppose you could experiment with adding back your own layer that rendered the background/border the way you wanted to.

Comment: Great hack, thank you. A couple of notes: you need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. Also, remember to dismiss the popover controller before any rotation, otherwise you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Removing the layer is a very bad idea and you'll probably be rejected by apple when submitting to appStore. Look at this solution here : https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Answer (score 7):

> How to remove iPad's popover view's arrow?

When calling -presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:, pass 0 as the second parameter, rather than any of the constants. This isn't documented, but Apple is allowing apps in the App Store when using this setting.

Comment: That does the work. However the popup gets resized and its width cannot be changed if you use UIImagePicker as content view.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the chrome around the popover. Your best bet is to reimplement the idea of a popover, but using custom code.

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot remove the arrow or the border. If you do some kind of hack, as suggested by TomSwift, you risk **crashes** and **refusal from apple** when submitting your app for appStore.
- You can implement your own custom popover like controller though, as suggested by Kevin.
  You can find an opensource project doing just that over here : https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover . Backgound and arrow can be remove from that one or set as transparent.