# Couldn't find any solution for remove the border of my popover

Tags: ios6, uipopover

I am using Uipopover view.When i click on a button in my view controller a popover view appears.Now i want to remove the border of popover view which in rectangle form and black in color.I searched on it but couldn't get any solution.

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755786/how-to-remove-ipads-popover-arrow-and-its-frame-border.

Comment: Hey i found it i used DDPopoverBackgroundView class and it worked.